# Tabular representation of the output of a bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a simple bat script which says if a IP is UP or DOWN.
Here's the code...

Here's the code...

```
ECHO OFF

ping 8.8.8.8 -n 1 > nul
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 echo Internet is [92mUp[0m
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 echo Internet is [91mDown[0m

ping 10.23.193.1 -n 1 > nul
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 echo VLAN 193 Gateway is [92mUp[0m
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 echo VLAN 193 Gateway is [91mDown[0m

ping 10.23.194.1 -n 1 > nul
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 echo VLAN 194 Gateway is [92mUp[0m
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 echo VLAN 194 Gateway is [91mDown[0m

pause
```

The output of the code is

```
Internet is Up
VLAN 193 Gateway is Down
VLAN 194 Gateway is Down
```

I want the output to be

```
Device            Status
Internet            Up
VLAN 193 Gateway   Down
VLAN 194 Gateway   Down
```

What changes would I need to make ?
I am new to batch scripting.

Comment: You mean "batch scripting", not "Bash scripting", right? Bash is a Unix shell and very different from batch scripting.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Apologies. Its batch scripting.

Comment: What have you tried to achieve the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Concatenate a string of blanks and use substring expansion to get a fixed column width
- Use CALLed subroutines to reuse code. Easier to maintain when you want to change the format since you only have to change once for many rows.
- Use variables for constants, again making it easier to make changes. Delayed expansion is useful in this case.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set "width=20"  Width of column 1, Current code supports value up to 80

call :print Device Status
call :test 8.8.8.8 Internet
call :test 10.23.193.1 "VLAN 193 Gateway"
call :test 10.23.194.1 "VLAN 194 Gateway"
exit /b

:test  Address  Label
ping %1 -n 1 >nul && call :print %2 Up || call :print %2 Down
exit /b

:print  Col1  Col2
setlocal
set "c1=%~1                                                                          "
echo !c1:~0,%width%! %2
exit /b
```

It's possible to eliminate one of the routines via creative use of FOR loops. You may or may not find this easier to maintain:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set "width=20"  Width of column 1, Current code supports value up to 80

call :print Device Status
for %%S in (
  "8.8.8.8 Internet"
  "10.23.193.1 VLAN 193 Gateway"
  "10.23.194.1 VLAN 194 Gateway"
) do for /f "tokens=1*" %%A in (%%S) do (
  ping %%A -n 1 >nul && call :print "%%B" Up || call :print "%%B" Down
)
exit /b

:print  Col1  Col2
setlocal
set "c1=%~1                                                                          "
echo !c1:~0,%width%! %2
exit /b
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only do it by spacing out the characters until it suits your need. Like this works for me:

```
@echo off
ping 8.8.8.8 -n 1 >nul
echo Device             Status
IF %errorlevel% equ 1 echo Internet            Down
IF %errorlevel% equ 0 echo Internet             Up

ping 10.23.193.1 -n 1 > nul
IF %errorlevel% equ 1 echo VLAN 193 Gateway    Down
IF %errorlevel% equ 0 echo VLAN 193 Gateway     Up

ping 10.23.194.1 -n 1 > nul
IF %errorlevel% equ 1 echo VLAN 194 Gateway    Down
IF %errorlevel% equ 0 echo VLAN 194 Gateway     Up
```